# php google weather api query

Tags: php, google-weather-api

I'm having trouble retrieving data from the google api. When I run the code, it only returns a blank page and not a printout of the xml array. Here is the code:

```
$url="http://www.google.com/ig/api";

$ch = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "?weather=london,england");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 


echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Is not XML array, just normal string. You need something extra to parse these string into XML

Comment: **The Google weather API was shut down in 2012** -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145820/google-weather-api-gone/35943521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you use POST method, and not the GET
Try like this

```
$url="http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=london,england";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$data = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

Hope it helps :)

EDIT: And yes, you have to do some extra parsing to get the data from the XML string